# How do I create a new ruby project in Eclipse indigo

Tags: ruby, eclipse-indigo

I have installed the following:
Dynamic Languages Toolkit - Ruby Development Tools  3.0.0.v20110424-7Z--E_EkMYXO4k101442

On

Eclipse Platform
Version: 3.7.2
Build id: I20110613-1736

But when I go to new projects, I see no sign of "Ruby Projects". 
All I have is File > New > Projects 
Then it opens a wizard in which I have a choice of General > Project (only)

After which it goes through the usual procedure of naming the project and voila.

I have added a new .rb file in my project and I see no interpreter kicking in for ruby either.

So for the moment eclipse looks like a very advanced notepad...

Can someone point to me what I'm missing?

Thank you

Comment: My problem really seems to be that the ruby toolkit did not install properly. There is no traces of ruby anywhere (perspective, interpreter, projects)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please follow the steps below.

1. Install ruby
2. Install eclipse (Ex: Eclipse Juno)
3. Now, install Dynamic Languages Toolkit (DLTK)

   - In Eclipse go to Help -> Install New Software
   - Click on Add button
   - Enter Name as DLTK
   - Enter Location as http://download.eclipse.org/technology/dltk/updates/
   - Click ok
4. Select the version and click on Next button
5. Complete the installation

**Enabling Ruby Perspective:**

1. In Eclipse go to Window -> Open Perspective
2. Select Others..
3. Select Ruby and click on Ok button

Note: You can save this perspective from Window -> Save Perspective As..

**Adding Ruby Interpreter in Eclipse:**

1. In Eclipse goto Window -> Preferences
2. Select Ruby -> Interpreters
3. Click on Search button
4. Select exe and click on Ok button

**Hello World:**

When above all setup is done correctly you should see Ruby Project in File -> New

1. Create a new Ruby Project
2. Add a new class file
3. Enter puts "Hello World!!"
4. Click on Ruby Script
5. You should be able to see Hello World in the console

*Happy Ruby learning!!!*

Comment: This worked for me. Only In the "Adding Ruby Interpreter in Eclipse: "step I had to manually add the interpreter. My ruby.exe was in C:\Ruby23-x64\bin